# How to get properties of vertex or edge elements in Titan DB version 1.0.0

Tags: java, titan

In older version of **Titan DB (ver 0.5.2)** the **TitanVertex** and **TitanEdge** implement **TitanElement** interface that has method `getProperties(String key)` that I used to retrieve the element properties values. This method was removed in new version of Titan (I am using version 1.0.0). Instead of this method I found `valueOrNull(PropertyKey key)` that does the same thing but receives **PropertyKey** as parameter and not **String** as key name.

What is the best way to retrieve the property value/values only using property key name as String object?

Or is there simple way to get PropertyKey object from property key name as String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titan 1.0 is based on TinkerPop 3. In Titan 1.0, you will find that some methods that you previously called in Titan 0.5 are defined in the TinkerPop interfaces, not in the Titan interfaces.

Looking at the Javadoc for `com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanVertex`, you can see that it extends `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex`
http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/1.0.0/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanVertex.html

You can find the method `VertexProperty property(String key)` on `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex` http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/javadocs/3.0.1-incubating/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Vertex.html#property-java.lang.String-

The best way to retrieve the property values on a vertex by using the property key is like this:

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.build().set('storage.backend','inmemory').open()
==>standardtitangraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[standardtitangraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]], standard]
gremlin> v = graph.addVertex('name', 'octopus')
==>v[4296]
gremlin> v.values('name')
==>octopus
```

You can learn more about vertex properties in the TinkerPop3 documentation here http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#vertex-properties

Comment: Thank you! It is very useful reference for TinkerPop3 documentation. But I am developing java application using thinkaurelius/titan package  [https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan). I still trying to find the simple and efficient way to retrieve vertex/edge property using java code. It must be very simple I think just missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time and found some simple solution of my problem (based on updated answer of Jason Plurad).

Looking at the Javadoc for `com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanElement` the method `valueOrNull(PropertyKey key)` receives the property key object. The easiest way to get this object is using `getPropertyKey(String keyName)` method of `com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanTransaction` that return the property key if it exist in Titan schema. http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/1.0.0/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanTransaction.html

Example of Java code:

```
TitanTransaction tt = TitanGraph.newTransaction();
PropertyKey userNameKey = tt.getPropertyKey("userName");
TitanVertex v = tt.getVertex(someUserVertexId);
String userName = v.valueOrNull(userNameKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
var = edge.inVertex().property("property").value();
```

Comment: This solution can be useful but it requires to check that the the property on the vertex exists otherwise it will throw exception. So I think that the usage of `vertex.valueOrNull(propertyKey)` method is better in this case.