# How to add properties for TitanVertext in titan graph 1.0.0

Tags: titan

I am using titan 1.0.0-hadoop1. I am trying to add some list of properties to Vertex that i am creating. In earlier versions such as 0.5.4 you can add property directly with setProperty, but in latest API i find it difficult to add property. I could not even find right solution in the internet.

Please help me in adding the properties to Vertex in Titan Java API.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065724/how-to-get-properties-of-vertex-or-edge-elements-in-titan-db-version-1-0-0

Answer (score 1):

An example will help:

```
Vertex vertex = graph.addVertex();
vertex.property("ID", "123"); //Creates ID property with value 123
```

creates the property.
To query the property:

```
vertex.property("ID"); //Returns the property object
vertex.value("ID");    //Returns "123"
vertex.values();       //Returns all the values of all the properties
```

When you having difficulty understanding the Titan API. I recommend looking at the [TinkerPop API](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/). Titan implements it so all tinkerpop commands work with titan graphs.

Comment: Adding to Fido's good answer, Titan 1.0.0 uses TinkerPop 3.0.1, so make sure you use the matching documentation. http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#vertex-properties

Answer (score 0):

I am also using **titan 1.0.0** graph database with cassandra storage backend and has the same problem after upgrading from 0.5.4 version. I found simple generic solution to add any `Collection` object (`Set` or `List`) to the vertex property using this method.

```
public static void setMultiElementProperties(TitanElement element, String key, Collection collection) {
    if (element != null && key != null && collection != null) {
        // Put item from collection to the property of type Cardinality.LIST or Cardinality.SET
        for (Object item : collection) {
            if (item != null)
                element.property(key, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Same method implementation with **Java 8** syntacs:

```
public static void setMultiElementProperties(TitanElement element, String key, Collection collection) {
    if (element != null && key != null && collection != null) {
        // Put item from collection to the property of type Cardinality.LIST or Cardinality.SET
        collection.stream().filter(item -> item != null).forEach(item -> element.property(key, item));
    }
}
```

`TitanElement` object is the parent of `TitanVertex` and `TitanEdge` objects so you can pass vertex or edge to this method. Of course you need to declare element property first with **Cardinality.Set** or **Cardinality.List** using TitanManagement to use the multi value property.

```
TitanManagement tm = tittanGraph.openManagement();
tm.makePropertyKey(key).cardinality(Cardinality.LIST).make();// or Cardinality.SET
tm.commit();
```

To retrieve the collection from element property you can simple use:

```
Iterator<Object> collectionIter = element.values(key);
```

And this is Java 8 way to iterate over it:

```
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();
collectionIter.forEachRemaining(item -> myList.add(item));
```